# Worksheet!C295 -> Formula Error: Operator ':' has no operands

Tags: excel, laravel, maatwebsite-excel

after a deep searching on google without finding any solution.
I'm using Laravel Excel Maatwebsite package.
I've already tried setting the calculate parameter on excel config file to false.
I found a row on the database that contains this value "=_DateRDV:" but I need to need to keep it on the result excel

When I try to export a database query result to excel I get this error :

PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Calculation\Exception
Worksheet!C295 -> Formula Error: Operator ':' has no operands

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Excel cell starting with `=` is considered to be a formula
`=_DateRDV:` is not a valid Excel formula, that's why it's giving you an error.
You need to either add an apostrophe in front `'=_DateRDV:`, or change cell format to text (which I think will basically add `'` in front of your text